# Windows 7 user profiles all appear as "unknown account"

Tags: active-directory, windows-7

I just started working as admin in a Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2 environment. Lately I encountered a strange behaviour of the profile service on some user notebooks: in the list of user profiles, all accounts are displayed as "unknown account", except the one I logged in with and the standard account. 
However, there are multiple folders in the C:\Users directory belonging to profiles that exist in the Active Directory domain, and at least one is regularly being used on the machine. Without problems, as far as I know.

Any explanations for this behaviour? 
It keeps me from properly deleting profiles on the machine, as I don't know which "unknown account" is which.

Comment: do those laptops have a working network connection with a domain controller when you test that?

Comment: `echo %LOGONSERVER%` returns the name of the domain controller. but `nltest /dsgetdc:<domain-name>` returns error, status 1355 ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN